# SubReportes en Crystal Reports no carga información

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Tengo un par de reportes que funcionan bastante bien por separado. He usado para esto Crystal Reports y VB.Net.

El problema está cuando intento crear un Sub-Reporte, aparece la información del reporte "contenedor" pero no me muestra la información del sub-reporte.

He creado un video y lo he colgado en YouTube para aquellos que quieran ayudar puedan orientarse mejor. Este es el [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jJjviu4dcY).

**Código**

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.DataTableExtensions
Imports System.Data.DataRowExtensions
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared

Public Class Form1
    Dim cn As OleDbConnection
    Dim ruta As String
    Dim restantes As Integer = 15 ' variable que controla las cadenas restantes.
    Dim cont As Integer = 0 'este contador lo creé porque en tres oportunidades me carga el dgColumn, quiero evitar varios messagesbox.show
    Dim cadena As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        "Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes'"

Sub Cargar(etiqueta As String)
    ' MessageBox.Show("select * from [" & etiqueta & "]")
    Try
        ' Preguntamos "si no es" DataRowView entonces quiere decir que estamos hablando de hojas que sí existen.
        If Not (etiqueta = "System.Data.DataRowView") Then
            ' Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select top 1 * from [" & etiqueta & "]", cn)
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from [" & etiqueta & "]", cn)

            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

            cn.Open()
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            cn.Close()

            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            dgExcel.DataSource = dt
            'cargarCampos()
            'gbCampos.Enabled = True
            gbCarta.Enabled = True
            lblColumnasCarta.Text = "0 Columnas"
            lblFilasCarta.Text = "0 Filas"
            'For col As Integer = 0 To dgExcel.Columns.Count - 1
            '    dgExcel.Columns(col).Visible = False
            '    dgExcel.Columns(col).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable 'Lo configuramos para que no se ordene al hacer click
            'Next
            'dgColumnas.Enabled = True
            cboHojas.Enabled = True
            dgExcel.Enabled = True
            dgExcel.ReadOnly = True
            cboOrden.Enabled = True
            btnListaUnica.Enabled = True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

' Función que es utilizada para cargar las etiquetas en el combobox.
Sub Etiquetas()
    Dim filePath As String = txtRuta.Text
    Dim connString As String = String.Empty
    If filePath.EndsWith(".xlsx") Then            '2007 Format            
        connString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'", filePath)
    Else            '2003 Format            
        connString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'", filePath)
    End If         'Get the Sheets in Excel WorkBook        
    Dim connExcel As New OleDbConnection(connString)
    Dim cmdExcel As New OleDbCommand()
    Dim oda As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel
    connExcel.Open()
    cboHojas.DataSource = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
    cboHojas.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME"
    cboHojas.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME"
    connExcel.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnCargar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCargar.Click
    Dim op As New OpenFileDialog
    op.Filter = "archivo de excel 12.0|*.xlsx"
    If op.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        cadena = String.Format(cadena, op.FileName)
        ruta = op.FileName
        txtRuta.Text = ruta
        cn = New OleDbConnection(cadena)
        ' Buscamos las etiquetas
        Etiquetas()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cboHojas_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboHojas.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' Obtenemos la etiqueta del combobox para luego cargar su contenido.
    Dim etiqueta As String = cboHojas.Text.ToString
    Cargar(etiqueta)
    For i As Integer = 0 To dgExcel.Columns.Count - 1
        cboOrden.Items.Add(dgExcel.Columns(i).HeaderCell.Value)
    Next
    'cargarCampos()
End Sub

Sub limpiarDatos(col)
    For fil As Integer = 0 To dgExcel.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim valor As String = dgExcel.Rows(fil).Cells(col).Value
        If Not (dgExcel.Rows(fil).Cells(col).Value = Nothing) Then
            ReemplazosChars(valor, fil, col)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub ReemplazosChars(ByVal valor As String, ByVal fil As Integer, ByVal col As Integer)
    dgExcel.Rows(fil).Cells(col).Value = valor.Replace("""", "")
    valor = dgExcel.Rows(fil).Cells(col).Value
    dgExcel.Rows(fil).Cells(col).Value = valor.Replace("'", "")
    valor = dgExcel.Rows(fil).Cells(col).Value
    dgExcel.Rows(fil).Cells(col).Value = valor.Replace("{", "")
    valor = dgExcel.Rows(fil).Cells(col).Value
    dgExcel.Rows(fil).Cells(col).Value = valor.Replace("}", "")
    valor = dgExcel.Rows(fil).Cells(col).Value
    dgExcel.Rows(fil).Cells(col).Value = valor.Replace("  ", " ")
    valor = dgExcel.Rows(fil).Cells(col).Value
    dgExcel.Rows(fil).Cells(col).Value = UCase(valor)
End Sub

Private Sub cboOrden_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboOrden.SelectedIndexChanged
    dgExcel.Sort(dgExcel.Columns(cboOrden.Text), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
    Dim col As Integer = dgExcel.Columns(cboOrden.Text).Index
    dgExcel.Columns(col).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "00000000"
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Resize
    Me.CenterToScreen()
    dgExcel.AllowUserToOrderColumns = True
End Sub

' Cuando hacemos clic sobre el link de ayuda.
Private Sub lblAyuda_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles lblAyuda.LinkClicked
    frmPopup.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub dgExcel_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgExcel.CellDoubleClick
    Dim nombre_header As String = Nothing
    nombre_header = InputBox("Escriba el nuevo nombre del encabezado:", "Cambiar nombre al encabezado", , , )
    If Not nombre_header = Nothing Then
        ' Asignamos el nuevo nombre formateando a tipo "Titulo".
        dgExcel.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderCell.Value = StrConv(nombre_header, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
    End If
End Sub

Structure Clientes
    Dim documento As String
    Dim nombre As String
    Dim direccion As String
    Dim dep As String
    Dim pro As String
    Dim dis As String
End Structure

Private Sub btnListaUnica_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnListaUnica.Click
    dgListaUnica.Rows.Clear()
    dgListaUnica.Columns(0).Name = "Documento"
    dgListaUnica.Columns(1).Name = "Cliente"
    dgListaUnica.Columns(2).Name = "Dirección"
    dgListaUnica.Columns(3).Name = "Dep"
    dgListaUnica.Columns(4).Name = "Pro"
    dgListaUnica.Columns(5).Name = "Dis"

    Try
        Dim listaClientes As New List(Of Clientes)

        If (cboOrden.Text = Nothing) Then
            cboOrden.BackColor = Color.Red
        Else
            cboOrden.BackColor = Color.White
        End If

        Dim cliente As New Clientes
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgExcel.Rows.Count - 1
            cliente.documento = dgExcel.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
            cliente.nombre = dgExcel.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
            cliente.direccion = dgExcel.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
            cliente.dep = dgExcel.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
            cliente.pro = dgExcel.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
            cliente.dis = dgExcel.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value

            listaClientes.Add(cliente)
        Next

        Dim resultados As List(Of Clientes) = listaClientes.Distinct().ToList
        For Each cli As Clientes In resultados
            dgListaUnica.Rows.Add(cli.documento, cli.nombre, cli.direccion, cli.dep, cli.pro, cli.dis)
        Next
        ' Remover la última fila del datagrid si es vacía.
        dgListaUnica.Rows.RemoveAt(dgListaUnica.Rows.Count - 1)
        dgListaUnica.Columns(1).Width = 350

        'For Each cli As Clientes In listaClientes
        '    dgListaUnica.Rows.Add(cli.documento, cli.nombre, cli.direccion, cli.dep, cli.pro, cli.dis)
        'Next

        lblTotalListaUnica.Text = dgListaUnica.Rows.Count - 1 & " Filas devueltas"
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnGenerar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGenerar.Click

    Dim dtLU As New DataTable
    subInforme()
    Try
        With dtLU
            .Columns.Add("Documento")
            .Columns.Add("Nombre")
            .Columns.Add("Direccion")
            .Columns.Add("Dep")
            .Columns.Add("Pro")
            .Columns.Add("Dis")
        End With

        ' Llenar el DataTable de los da tos únicos
        For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In Me.dgListaUnica.Rows
            dtLU.Rows.Add(dr.Cells(0).Value, dr.Cells(1).Value, dr.Cells(2).Value, dr.Cells(3).Value, dr.Cells(4).Value, dr.Cells(5).Value)
        Next


        Dim rptLUni As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument

        rptLUni = New rptCartas
        rptLUni.SetDataSource(dtLU)

        frmReporte.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptLUni
        frmReporte.ShowDialog()
        frmReporte.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Sub subInforme()
    Try
        Dim dtXls As New DataTable

        With dtXls
            .Columns.Add("Documento")
            .Columns.Add("Nombre")
            .Columns.Add("Direccion")
            .Columns.Add("Dep")
            .Columns.Add("Pro")
            .Columns.Add("Dis")
            .Columns.Add("NCuenta")
            .Columns.Add("Producto")
            .Columns.Add("DiasMora")
            .Columns.Add("Moneda")
            .Columns.Add("DeudaTotal")
            .Columns.Add("Campana")
            .Columns.Add("Cartera") ' Proveedor
            .Columns.Add("Subcartera")
            .Columns.Add("Plaza")
            .Columns.Add("DireccionOficinaSede")
            .Columns.Add("TelefonoOficinaSede")
        End With

        ' Llenar el DataTable de los detalles
        For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In Me.dgExcel.Rows
            dtXls.Rows.Add(
                dr.Cells(0).Value, dr.Cells(1).Value, dr.Cells(2).Value, dr.Cells(3).Value, dr.Cells(4).Value, dr.Cells(5).Value, _
            dr.Cells(6).Value, dr.Cells(7).Value, dr.Cells(8).Value, dr.Cells(9).Value, dr.Cells(10).Value, dr.Cells(11).Value, _
            dr.Cells(12).Value, dr.Cells(13).Value, dr.Cells(14).Value, dr.Cells(15).Value, dr.Cells(16).Value)
        Next

        Dim rptXls As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
        'rptXls = New rptDetalles
        rptXls = New rptDetalles2
        rptXls.SetDataSource(dtXls)

        frmSubReporte.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptXls
        frmSubReporte.ShowDialog()
        frmSubReporte.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGuardar.Click
    subInforme()
End Sub 
End Class
```

**[EDITO]**

Adjunto una imagen para intentar comprender mejor mi caso. Me disculpo por censurar la información confidencial de la empresa donde trabajo, espero su comprensión:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La primera parte del código no se muestra en el contenedor de código fuente, espero no cause problemas para entender mi código.

Comment: Bienvenido! Te invito a pasar por [tour inicial](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y mirar también [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link para tener en cuenta al momento de formular preguntas, puede que te interese [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) que trata de que hacer al momento de recibir una respuesta.
Si has encontrado una respuesta por tu cuenta, puede que te interese ver [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu apoyo, lo haré!